# Add column to Tfidf matrix

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, nltk

I want to build a classification model on text using the words as well as some additional features (e.g., has links)

```
tweets = ['this tweet has a link htt://link','this one does not','this one does http://link.net']
```

I used sklearn to get a sparse matrix of my text data

`tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.90, max_features=200000,
                                 min_df=0.1, stop_words='english',
                                 use_idf=True, ntlk.tokenize,ngram_range=(1,2))`

`tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(tweets)`

I want to add columns to it to support additional features of my text data. I have tried:

```
import scipy as sc
```

`all_data = sc.hstack((tfidf_matrix, [1,0,1]))`

This gives me data that looks like this:

`array([ <3x8 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 10 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
       1, 1, 0], dtype=object)`

When I feed this data frame to a model:

```
`from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
 clf = MultinomialNB().fit(all_data, y)`
```

I get a traceback error:

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site- packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 580, in   runfile
 execfile(filename, namespace)
 File "C:/Users/c/Desktop/features.py", line 157, in <module>
 clf = MultinomialNB().fit(all_data, y)
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py", line 302, in  fit
_, n_features = X.shape
```

ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack`

Edit: The shape of the data

```
`tfidf_matrix.shape
 (100, 2)
 all_data.shape
 (100L,)`
```

Can I append columns directly to a sparse matrix? If not, how should I convert the data to a format that can support this? I worry that something other than a sparse matrix will increase the memory footprint.

Comment: Please post the whole traceback.

Comment: Does it work simply with `MultinomialNB().fit(tfidf_matrix, y) `?

Comment: @AlexPlugaru Hi Alex. It works I just use the tfidf_matrix. Without trying to append the other column.

Comment: What is the `shape` of the `tfidf_matrix` and `all_data` perhaps it doesn't match? Maybe you should do this:  all_data = sc.hstack((tfidf_matrix, [[1],[0],[1]])) as explained here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.hstack.html

Comment: It seems that the shape for the features is missing. Maybe you should do a reshape: `all_data.reshape(tfidf_matrix.shape)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Convert the sparse matrix into a dense matrix

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
tweets = ['this tweet has a link htt://link','this one does not','this one does http://link.net']

tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(tweets)
dense = tfidf_matrix.todense()
print dense.shape

newCol = [[1],[0],[1]]

allData = np.append(dense, newCol, 1)

print allData.shape
```

## (3L, 10L)

## (3L, 11L)

Answer (score 13):

"Can I append columns **directly** to a **sparse** matrix?" - Yes. And you probably should, since unpacking (using `todense` or `toarray`) can easily cause memory explosions in a large corpus.

Using [scipy.sparse.hstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.hstack.html):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

tweets = ['this tweet has a link htt://link','this one does not','this one does http://link.net']
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(tweets)
print tfidf_matrix.shape
```

(3, 10)

```
new_column = np.array([[1],[0],[1]])
print new_column.shape
```

(3, 1)

```
final = sp.sparse.hstack((tfidf_matrix, new_column))
print final.shape
```

(3, 11)

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct form:

```
all_data = sc.hstack([tfidf_matrix, sc.csr_matrix([1,0,1]).T], 'csr')
```